# Why isn't my variable being updated and my LEDs don't go on?

Tags: c++

Working on a code project using an arduino, but things seem to not work and I'm not exactly sure why. I intended it to use the A-D buttons on a 16 key keypad to change a variable called activeSlot, which would then change what actual slot the number keys would write to when pressed. Things don't seem to work though, and I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'D','C','B','A'},
  {'#','9','6','3'},
  {'0','8','5','2'},
  {'*','7','4','1'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
```

basic keypad setup

```
//the amount of energy in each slot
int slotA = 0;
int slotB = 0;
int slotC = 0;
int slotD = 0;

//the amount of energy in the other slots, set to 0 at the beginning
int totalA = 0;
int totalB = 0;
int totalC = 0;
int totalD = 0;

//the total allocated energy, used for lighting the correct number of LEDs
int totalE = 0;

int activeSlot[] = {0};
int x = activeSlot[0];
```

Setup for integers, all start at 0 and *should* be changed in the loop section

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

//pinMode(2,INPUT);
//pinMode(3,INPUT);
//pinMode(4,INPUT);
//pinMode(5,INPUT);
//pinMode(6,INPUT);
//pinMode(7,INPUT);
//pinMode(8,INPUT);
//pinMode(9,INPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
pinMode(14,OUTPUT);
pinMode(15,OUTPUT);
pinMode(16,OUTPUT);
pinMode(17,OUTPUT);
pinMode(18,OUTPUT);
pinMode(19,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

configures pins

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  //the amount of energy in the other slots, set to 0 at the beginning
  int totalA = 10 - (slotB + slotC + slotD);
  int totalB = 10 - (slotA + slotC + slotD);
  int totalC = 10 - (slotA + slotB + slotD);
  int totalD = 10 - (slotA + slotB + slotC);
```

There should be 10 energy/points to allocate to any slot. totalA is the starting 10 - the energy in each other slot. If there is less energy left than the number key you press for that slot, it shouldn't change the variable.

```
  // section for active slot keypress actions
   if (key == 'A'){activeSlot[0] = 1;
   Serial.println(x = activeSlot[0]);
   }
   if (key == 'B'){activeSlot[0] = 2;
   Serial.println(x = activeSlot[0]);
   }
   if (key == 'C'){activeSlot[0] = 3;
   Serial.println(x = activeSlot[0]);
   }
   if (key == 'D'){activeSlot[0] = 4;
   Serial.println(x = activeSlot[0]);
   }

x = activeSlot[0];

//1 energy section
if(key == '1');          //if _ is pressed
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1); //if the slot is A
    if(totalA >= 1);     //if A has at least _ energy
      slotA = 1;         //set A to _
                   //B section
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 1);
      slotB = 1;
                   //C section
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 1);
      slotC = 1;
                   //D section
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 1);
      slotD = 1;

//2 energy section
if(key == '2');          
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1); 
    if(totalA >= 2);   
      slotA = 2;       
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 2);
      slotB = 2;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 2);
      slotC = 2;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 2);
      slotD = 2;
//3 energy section
if(key == '3');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 3);  
      slotA = 3;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 3);
      slotB = 3;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 3);
      slotC = 3;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 3);
      slotD = 3;
//4 energy section
if(key == '4');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 4);  
      slotA = 4;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 4);
      slotB = 4;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 4);
      slotC = 4;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 4);
      slotD = 4;
//5 energy section
if(key == '5');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 5);  
      slotA = 5;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 5);
      slotB = 5;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 5);
      slotC = 5;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 5);
      slotD = 5;
//6 energy section
if(key == '6');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 6);  
      slotA = 6;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 6);
      slotB = 6;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 6);
      slotC = 6;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 6);
      slotD = 6;
//7 energy section
if(key == '7');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 7);  
      slotA = 7;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 7);
      slotB = 7;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 7);
      slotC = 7;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 7);
      slotD = 7;
//0 energy section
if(key == '0');         
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1);
    if(totalA >= 0);  
      slotA = 0;    
  if(activeSlot[0] = 2);
    if(totalB >= 0);
      slotB = 0;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 3);
    if(totalC >= 0);
      slotC = 0;
  if(activeSlot[0] = 4);
    if(totalD >= 0);
      slotD = 0;


  //the amount of energy used in all the slots, for the LEDs
  int totalE = slotA + slotB + slotC + slotD;
```

this section checks for a pressed number key. If one is pressed, it checks the activeSlot for what slot to change. If the total energy left is enough, it then should change that slot to the value of the number key pressed.

```
//LED SECTION
if(totalE == 0){
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 1){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 2){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 3){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 4){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 5){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 6){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(16,LOW);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 7){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(17,LOW);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 8){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(17,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(18,LOW);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 9){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(17,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(18,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(19,LOW);
}
if(totalE == 10){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(17,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(18,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(19,HIGH);
}

if(key == '#'){
  Serial.println(x = activeSlot[0]);
}
if(key == '*'){
  Serial.println(x = totalE);
}

//end of void loop
}
```

This is the LED section. I intended it to check the totalE (the total value of each slot) and use that for lighting up the correct number of LEDs. totalE at 0 means none are lit up, 1 means 1 is lit up, etc.. It doesn't seem to do anything, and totalE doesn't seem to change. For some reason, activeSlot[0] is always stuck at 4 as well.

Answer (score 3):

This section of code

```
if(key == '1');          //if _ is pressed
  if(activeSlot[0] = 1); //if the slot is A
    if(totalA >= 1);     //if A has at least _ energy
      slotA = 1;         //set A to _
```

is almost certainly not doing what you expect. The semicolon `;` after each `if` statement terminates the `if` statement, and executes nothing. The lines following each `if` statement are then executed unconditionally, as if there was no `if` condition guarding on them (because as written, there is not). Further, you're assigning values to `activeSlot[0]` (`activeSlot[0] = 1`) instead of checking for equality. You want `if (activeSlot[0] == 1)`. Your current code can be rewritten (with indentation indicating scoping) as

```
if(key == '1');        //if '1' is pressed, do nothing
if(activeSlot[0] = 1); //assign the value of 1 to activeSlot[0], then do nothing
if(totalA >= 1);       //if A has at least 1 energy, do nothing
slotA = 1;             //set A to 1
```

You most likely want to rewrite this as

```
if(key == '1')           //if _ is pressed
  if(activeSlot[0] == 1) //if the slot is A
    if(totalA >= 1)      //if A has at least _ energy
      slotA = 1;         //set A to _
```

Note the lack of semicolons after the `if` statements, and the boolean `==` operator instead of assignment `=`.

At the end of your entire chain of `if` statements and variable assignments you have (rewritten to show behavior better)

```
if(key == '0');        // do nothing 
if(activeSlot[0] = 1); // activeSlot[0] always gets assigned 1
if(totalA >= 0);       // do nothing
slotA = 0;             // this happens always
if(activeSlot[0] = 2); // activeSlot[0] always gets assigned 2
if(totalB >= 0);       // do nothing 
slotB = 0;             // this happens always
if(activeSlot[0] = 3); // activeSlot[0] always gets assigned 3
if(totalC >= 0);       // do nothing
slotC = 0;             // this happens always
if(activeSlot[0] = 4); // activeSlot[0] always gets assigned 4 (overwriting all previous assignments)
if(totalD >= 0);       // do nothing
slotD = 0;             // this happens always
```